# Salvando a imagem real Picturebox

Tags: vb.net, picturebox

Estou tentando salvar o conteúdo de uma picturebox, mas sempre salva a imagem original e não a que está sendo apresentado.
Alguém pode me ajudar?

[image: Exemplo]

```
Dim myEncoder As Encoder
    Dim myImageCodecInfo As ImageCodecInfo
    Dim myEncoderParameter As EncoderParameter
    Dim myEncoderParameters As EncoderParameters
    Dim bmp As Bitmap = CType(imgJpgPng.Image, Bitmap)
    Dim bmpt As New Bitmap(640, 640)
    Using g As Graphics = Graphics.FromImage(bmpt)
        g.DrawImage(bmp, 0, 0, bmpt.Width, bmpt.Height)
    End Using
    myImageCodecInfo = GetEncoderInfo(ImageFormat.Jpeg)
    myEncoder = Encoder.Quality
    myEncoderParameters = New EncoderParameters(1)
    myEncoderParameter = New EncoderParameter(myEncoder, CType(75L, Int32))
    myEncoderParameters.Param(0) = myEncoderParameter
    bmpt.Save("d:\TempImg\0000.JPG", myImageCodecInfo, myEncoderParameters)
```

Comment: Você precisará fazer o crop da imagem via programação, pois o que aparece no controle é apenas uma exibição recortada da imagem, e não uma nova imagem que pode ser salva. Por exemplo, se a pessoa escolher "center" você precisa aplicar esse código ao salvar http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18014365/c-sharp-crop-image-from-center e assim em diante. Pessoalmente eu preferiria usar o imagemagick pra fazer isso

Comment: Veja se isso pode te ajudar: http://www.vb-helper.com/howto_resize_picture_save.html